# When is Fork/Join executor preferred to a Thread Pool executor in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, fork-join

What **example real world scenarios** would justify using a fork/join executor instead of a thread pool executor in Java 7/8?

Comment: Why the -1's? it is not great when people -1 and do not tell you why.

Comment: Agreed, and this isn't "too broad" a question either (although it might be a duplicate). A fork-join pool has the feature of work stealing: when your executing task calls `join()`, it *potentially gives up its thread to another task.* This is useful for applications like a parallel merge sort: with a normal executor service, you kick off tasks for the child sorts, but your parent task still holds the thread while waiting for the children. As a result, you quickly run out of threads. The fork-join pool, by comparison, will potentially take the parent task's thread to run the child task.

Answer (score 1):

The fork-join framework should be used for tasks that can be broken into smaller pieces recursively. 
You could do this with simple thread pools, but then you would need to write a lot more code.

Search for "divide and conquer algorithm" on the web, and you will find plenty of examples.